# Rails 4.2 not creating non-digested-assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, precompile, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am working on **Rails 4.2.0** . As per rails 4 new assets pipeline policy while precompiling only digested assets are creating. I am using AWS Cloudfront for serving static assets. So along with precompiling I am pushing the compiled assets to cloudfront using **gem asset_sync** . But I am facing an issue. I am serving some images as given below.

```
<%= image_tag "/assets/defaults/some_name.png" %> 
<img src="<%= asset_path("/assets/img/some_name.gif") %>" style="height:20px; margin: 0 5px;"/>
```

And some images in some  **.scss**  files as given below.

```
 background: url(/assets/img/some_name.png) no-repeat;
```

But these images are not serving properly because there is no files in the original name. Only digested version is available. Same issue is happening for some font files I am using. SO any one please help me with a solution for how to serve digested images using  **image_tag**  or creating non digested assets.

Answer (score 1):

You can access images in following ways.

```
<%= image_tag "defaults/some_name.png" %> 
<img src="<%= asset_path("img/some_name.gif") %>" style="height:20px; margin: 0 5px;"/>
background: url(asset-path('img/some_name.png')) no-repeat;
```